# How to combine sherlock and viewpageindicator?

Tags: android

Hey I am new in android develop. 
I am now try to use both sherlock library and viewpageindicator together, but I can't. 
**Could you post tutorial how we combine those two ?**

Thank

Comment: Extend SherlockActivity instead of Activity etc.

Answer (score 2):

Below is the link which contains sample program for combining sherlock and view page indicator.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/

I  hope you to study the full sample and analyse whole program you can understand the concept easily .

This will  provide a useful information for you my friend.

Comment: Thank, but This is only viewpageindicator not both

Answer (score 1):

You should modify Shelock Action Bar source code a little bit (change extends from Activity to FragmentActivity)

From:

```
public abstract class SherlockActivity extends Activity
```

To:

```
public abstract class SherlockActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

(for implement View Page Indicator)

And then, build Sherlock Action Bar lib again, use it like normal.